# What Resources Are Available For Poison?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, game-recommendation, optimization, homebrew, poison

I find myself stopped up short in my efforts to create a major...well, not *antagonist*, but let us call him a very shady ally, for my PCs. The individual in question, Mykael the Grinner, is the master of a tribe of elves that favor incredibly toxic poisons, venoms, and chemical compounds. The trouble is that all the rules I can find for these substances (and spells that mimic them!) in 3.5 is highly underwhelming. Thus, I have two questions: are there any published resources that can help improve his lethal concoctions, and if not/in addition to those, does anyone have homebrew resources that they might suggest for such venoms?

Comment: Currently available resources for venoms, toxins, and more exotic compounds include the BoVD, the DMG/SRD, and a few Assassin spells that increase the effects of poisons. Unfortunately the DCs/deliveries tend to be underwhelming, and venoms of all varieties are hideously expensive

Comment: DC 56 poison is underwhelming? You're better off not using poisons at all, then. As for the cost, *minor creation* solves the problem.

Comment: A DC 56 poison is an on-off switch - either it works, or the victim is immune to poison in the first place. I'd rather seek homebrew than use such clumsy and ill-designed rules.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you here. Are you calling a system where poison immunity is possible ill-designed?

Comment: No, but relying solely on venoms that non-immune characters are incapable of resisting is sloppy. I'm looking to create a challenge, not an impossibility; if I wanted unstoppable effects I'd optimize a spell's save DC, not look into using/abusing/changing the poison rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add some homebrew poison support, here are a few:

- [A nasty Poisoner PrC](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=199414).
- [3.5 implementation of real-world poisons](http://e3.lemdal.com/TER/gamerules/poisonsnmaking.htm).
- [Rules for creating custom poisons](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=158131).

And to toot my own horn: I have performed an [overhaul of the 3.5 poison system](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=255288) myself. It's not so much an addition to as it is a replacement of the old mechanics, but it does make them significantly more usable, and less reliant on being expanded in the first place (but I *would* think that, of course).

Comment: I hadn't seen your Poison brew before, that's awesome. Also, probably worth noting: while the picture for the Poisoner PrC doesn't *really* reveal anything, it's probably NSFW (she's nude, facing away from the viewer, with a tail that covers her behind).

Comment: I'll review these the *very moment* I have some free time (I work twelve hours today!) but on first blush this is looking like something I'd want to use.

Comment: @KRyan personally knowing the author of that pic, she's not even a poison user

Answer (score 8):

The best resource available for 3.5 poisons is the [Arsenic and Old Lace handbook](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=2714.0).

Anyway, Master of Poisons from *Drow of the Underdark* is a must. For one feat, get poison use and the ability to apply poisons as a swift action. Levels in shaper to manifest *psionic minor creation* is also a tried-and-true way to get poisons en masse very cheaply. [Wild Cohort](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/re/20031118a) for a viper of some sort is also good for cheap poisons.

The variant bard found in [Athas.org’s *Dark Sun Campaign Setting*](http://athas.org/products/ds3) (a WotC-licensed but not WotC-published work) has some nifty poison-related features. They’re not amazing, though.

Answer (score 4):

[*Book of Vile Darkness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Vile_Darkness) is your best friend here, for it features poisons with really high DC. Unfortunately, the most potent ones are *injury* poisons.

The only caveat is the cost of the top poisons; it can be circumvented by liberal application of *minor creation* or by crafting cost mitigation.

Comment: *Complete Adventurer* has slightly modified rules for poison creation -- you get them at 1/6 the price instead of 1/3 when crafting.  I think it might also have a few additional poisons listed?  Haven't looked at it in a while.